how to pass the concatinated column from datagridview to another form with specified text boxes? vb.net, mysql xampp
im using vb.net and I've ran into a problem where i have to concatinate names (e.g. sName, fName, MI) in mysql and it successfully shown in my data grid but the problem was I cannot pass the concatinated data in different text boxes.
I also tried splitting them, but the problem was the instances where there are two words in a surname and it didn't accurately passed into the specified text box...

I've tried doing this... and it didn't work. im not good at this sorry! this is where i pass the data from FORM2 to FORM3 textboxes by MySQL column names (sName, fName, MIName)
FORM3.txtbx_snameREN.Text = dtgrdView.CurrentRow.Cells("sName").Value.ToString() ' Surname
FORM3.txtbx_fnameREN.Text = dtgrdView.CurrentRow.Cells("fName").Value.ToString() ' First Name
FORM3.txtbx_MI_REN.Text = dtgrdView.CurrentRow.Cells("MIName").Value.ToString() ' Middle Initial

SAMPLE OF MY CODE IN SPLIT.
Dim fullName As String = dtgrdView.CurrentRow.Cells("OwnerName").Value.ToString() 
Dim nameParts As String() = fullName.Split(" "c)

' Assigning values based on the specific order: 
If nameParts.Length > 0 Then FORM3.txtbx_snameREN.Text = nameParts(0) ' Surname (first part)
If nameParts.Length > 1 Then FORM3.txtbx_fnameREN.Text = nameParts(1) ' First Name (second part)
If nameParts.Length > 2 Then FORM3.txtbx_MI_REN.Text = nameParts(2) 'MI (third part)

this didnt work too because i have a data recorded named e.g. De Rama and when i pass to another form the "De" was in surname textbox and "Rama" was in the First name. please help me.

It is not easy to parse names into first and second names from a string. Consider storing these in separate columns, so you don't need to parse them.

The easiest way to do this is to store each component of the name in a separate field (last name, first name, middle initial) in MySQL and avoid concatenating in database queries.
This way you don't have to think about names with multiple words, especially if there are patterns (like two-word surnames)
